# Image not fading in? CSS

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to get the overlay to fade in but it's an immediate change now

HTML:

```
<div class="image-container">
    <img src="https://basicfishkeeping.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/01/Freshwater-Aquatic-Background-7.png" class="before">
    <img src="https://basicfishkeeping.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/01/Freshwater-Aquatic-Background-8.png" class="after">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.image-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
}
.image-container .before {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.image-container .after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
.image-container:hover .after {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Tried running it on Wordpress and got the immediate change to the second image instead of a fade over

Comment: `display: block` for `.image-container .after` should solve it. You can not animate `transition` property.

Comment: Remove display: none properly and use visibility: hidden

Comment: Can anyone explain why altering the display property affects whether opacity is animated or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following making the fading-in a transition:

```
.image-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
}
.image-container .before {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.image-container .after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
.image-container:hover .after {
    display: block;
}

.after:hover {
    transition: 0.5s;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: What if we remove display none and use visibilty: hidden it will simple work

Comment: @ahmedmoeed you don't even need the visibility property as the element has opacity 0 so cannot be seen (both will be rendered, just not seen).

Comment: Do you have an explanation for why altering the display affects whether opacity is animated or not?

Comment: Yes I understand that you might want display: none, but what I don't understand is why altering that property stops the opacity being transitioned.